# Return more than 250 results when searching messages in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am using the [`$search`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search) query parameter to search Office 365 messages through Microsoft Graph. This is my current implementation:

```
public async Task<List<ResultsItem>> MessageSearch(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string folderId, string search)
{
      List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
      {
            new QueryOption("$search", search)
      };

      IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage messages = await graphClient.Me.MailFolders[folderId].Messages.Request(options).Top(250).GetAsync();

      // further code omitted for brevity
}
```

The `$search` requests are limited to 250 results.

How can I work around this limitation and search messages with Microsoft Graph and obtain all of the results rather than just the first 250?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Including an example call and details about the scenario (i.e. how you're using the API) would provide the community with enough information to look for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks Marc! I have added code outlining the API call.

Answer (score 1):

The `$search` query param will only return the top 250 results. I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $search="xxxxxxxxx AND received:mm/dd/yyyy..mm/dd/yyyy"
```

I pass my search period as a variable and search in a callback loop